# How to load a table from a file to a program in C#?

Tags: c#, file-upload

I prepared a file with a table of ints. I looks like this:

```
int[] table = {
12,
56,
35,
86,
14,
5,
};
```

What's the easiest way to load it to my program in C#? The file is .ppm, but I think I can change the extention. I've seen in a video it's extremely easy in C - the guy just used `#include`. Is there something equally easy in C#? I cannot google out the answer. If not - how can I load it? I must load it from a file, because there is 170.000 lines...

Comment: if you remove the array declaration and commas it's as easy as `File.ReadAllLines(filename).Select(int.Parse).ToArray()`

Comment: I imported System.IO and I try to load it thus, but it marks my Select.

Comment: `using System.Linq`?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/N5c9s1

Comment: Now it works! Thank you very much :D How "standard" is this solution? ;P

Comment: If you have a file with a list of ints, you want to read the file and parse them as ints. It doesn't get any more ‘standard’ than this.